# Python 3.8 virtual environment not finding pip packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip, virtualenv

I have this folder that is one of my python projects, inside that folder is my project files, along with two folders. One folder is the python virtual environment for my Windows 10 PC, and the other is another virtual environment for my MacBook. I switch between the two a lot so I wanted to run my python project within VSCode itself for convince.

They both are using the same version of python.
My Windows 10 virtual environment works just like it should and my macOS version works, but cannot find the packages that I install within it. (I get an error that the 'packages' module couldn't be found) I've tried installing the packages within the virtual environment itself after I've activated it, I've also install the packages local to my macOS.

When I do a `pip list` from within the virtual environment, I get this:

[image]

So that above shows that, indeed, I do have the request module installed, yet I still get this error:

[image]

When I do the command `which python`, I get the correct version I was expecting. It's Python 3.8.3 located within my environment folder:

[image]

I've done everything the same as I did with my Windows version, so I don't see that I've done anything wrong?

Comment: can you do a `which pip`. Check if its the pip that python 3.8 or the one in your venv uses. Or you can jst do a `pip3 list` and see if the modules are actually loaded

Comment: Those two commands you just mentioned shows the exact same output at the two in my question respectively.

Comment: How are you calling your script?

Comment: @leoOrion from within my virtual environment. Not just a normal terminal. Hence why the name of my venv is to the left of every line in the terminal commands in the two screenshots above. But even if I do the same commands from within my venv or my local terminal, then the same commands are outputted anyway so.

Comment: Hmm.... I am not sure whats missing. Few things that might help or be completely redundant to what you have already checked. 1. Check the python version after u load your venv. Is it the same as when you dont load. 2. Have you tried calling your script using python3 executable directly ? If it works then there's something wrong with your venv. 3. Do a `pip3 install` on the requests and see if it works. 4. You can check the venv and your python directory(python2 and python3)  for the requests module itself. It should be there in `site-packages`. I honestly cant think of anything else.